# Cannot see my network on Windows 7 running under Parallels 10

Tags: network, imac, windows, parallels-desktop

I have 4 Sony laptops, a Seagate Central, 2 Wi-Fi printers and an iMac on my home network. The iMac running under OS X 10.10.3 can see all of the network devices using Finder. The laptops can see the iMac. BUT Windows on the iMac can only connect to the internet. Windows cannot see any of the network Laptops, the Seagate or the printers.

Apart from that Parallels works fine! I have emailed them for support but they have not responded. The machines are all networked via a Linksys XAC 1900 which works really well. I want to use the iMac as my #1 computer (it has more memory and disk than any of the laptops) but this network issue is making that impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the virtual network interface of your Windows 7 VM uses "Shared Network". Reconfigure the NIC to bridged network and choose Ethernet or Wi-Fi (like indicated in the screenshot below) depending on your network configuration:

- if your iMac is connected to the Linksys XAC 1900 via Ethernet choose "Ethernet"
- if your iMac is connected to the Linksys XAC 1900 via Wi-Fi choose "Wi-Fi"

[image]

You might want to check the Firewall configuration in your Windows 7 VM as well. If the settings are to restrictive the network devices won't be visible.